# How to create Typescript map?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a Map `total` which can be used like: `total['cashBalance'].sum`

based on existing data

```
const fields = ['cashBalance', 'openTradeEquity', 'initialMargin', 'optionValue', 'treasuries', 'margin'];
```

I am trying as below but it is not working.

```
const total: Map<string, {sum: number}> = fields.map(f => [f, {sum: 0}]) ;
```

Surely, I am not getting the syntax right... can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks
Anand

Comment: Please clarify *It's not working*

Comment: Did you mean "but it is _not_ working"? Also, instead of saying "it's not working", it would be more helpful to give an error message, or the result you got instead of what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array's `map` function creates a new array from an existing one, and doesn't create a map. Here, you want to use the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object instead. Loop through all of the items in `fields` and add an item to the map for each one.

```js
const total = new Map<string, { sum: number }>()
for (const field of fields) {
  total.set(field, { sum: 0 })
}

total.get('cashBalance').sum // 0
```

Comment: Shorter: `const total: Map<string, { sum: number }> = new Map(fields.map(f => [f, { sum: 0 }] as [string, { sum: number }]));`. Unfortunately the type cast is necessary.

Comment: I'd rather go with the readable approach over the shorter one

Comment: Thank you so  much @kingdaro